# How to reorder Wagtail admin menu items

Tags: django, wagtail

There are some custom menu items in the admin's menu, it is easy to order them (the items marked in red below).
Just set `menu_order` of the custom `ModelAdmin` object.

The question is how to reorder the built-in menu items, such as Pages, Images, Media, and Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`construct_main_menu` hook](https://docs.wagtail.org/en/stable/reference/hooks.html#construct-main-menu) to modify existing menu items.

For example, to move the Pages item to the bottom, place this code in a `wagtail_hooks.py` file within one of your apps:

```py
from wagtail import hooks

@hooks.register('construct_main_menu')
def reorder_menu_items(request, menu_items):
    for item in menu_items:
        if item.name == 'explorer':  # internal name for the Pages menu item
            item.order = 100000
            break
```